# Cucumber Scenario Outline: Passing empty string " " as value in Examples table

Tags: cucumber, string, cucumber-jvm

I have a cucumber scenario outline in which Examples table I would like to pass an empty string (" ") and line breaks (\n \n \n) as value. I want to edit an textfield and I am deleting the string and want to pass in the empty string or the line breaks. I want to send this value and press enter. This would look like this .sendKeys(value + "\n"). In the Example table just leaving the value blank and pass \n\n\n doesnt work. Value in textfield gets not changed.
This is how the Scenario outline looks like:

```
Scenario Outline: Do not accept erroneous input as group conversation name (only spaces and break lines)
Given I Sign in using login <Login> and password <Password>
And I see Contact list with name <Name>
And I create group chat with <Contact1> and <Contact2>
When I open conversation with <Contact1>, <Contact2>
And I open Conversation info
And I set name <NewName> for conversation
Then I do not see conversation <NewName> in contact list
And I see Contact list with name <Contact1>, <Contact2>

Examples: 
  | Login   | Password    | Name    | Contact1    | Contact2    | NewName       |
  | aqaUser | aqaPassword | aqaUser | aqaContact1 | aqaContact2 |               |
  | aqaUser | aqaPassword | aqaUser | aqaContact1 | aqaContact2 | \n\n\n\n      |
```

How do I pass the values?
When I am just passing the values as hardcoded it works. The textfield gets replaced at least with the values, but I would like to have it in as an placeholder .
Hard coded version:

```
Scenario Outline: Do not accept erroneous input as group conversation name (only spaces)
Given I Sign in using login <Login> and password <Password>
And I see Contact list with name <Name>
And I create group chat with <Contact1> and <Contact2>
When I open conversation with <Contact1>, <Contact2>
And I open Conversation info
And I set name     for conversation
Then I do not see conversation     in contact list
And I see Contact list with name <Contact1>, <Contact2>

Examples: 
  | Login   | Password    | Name    | Contact1    | Contact2    |
  | aqaUser | aqaPassword | aqaUser | aqaContact1 | aqaContact2 |

Scenario Outline: Do not accept erroneous input as group conversation name (line breaks)
Given I Sign in using login <Login> and password <Password>
And I see Contact list with name <Name>
And I create group chat with <Contact1> and <Contact2>
When I open conversation with <Contact1>, <Contact2>
And I open Conversation info
And I set name \n\n\n\n\n for conversation
Then I do not see conversation \n\n\n\n\n in contact list
And I see Contact list with name <Contact1>, <Contact2>

Examples: 
  | Login   | Password    | Name    | Contact1    | Contact2    |
  | aqaUser | aqaPassword | aqaUser | aqaContact1 | aqaContact2 |
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hi @julesmummdry! Did you finally use my solution? If so, maybe you could mark the answer as accepted if it helped

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to put the `<columnName>` between "" in your feature definition. Example:

```
And I set name "<NewName>" for conversation
```

In your step definition, the step could be annotated like as follows:

```
   @And("^And I set name \"([^\"]*)\" for conversation$")
   public void And_I_set_name_for_conversation(String newName) throws Throwable {
      ...
   }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, will try it...found in the mean time a differnt solution. So I pass the unicode character for SPACE and escape it (\\u0020). I have a Stringparser that unescapes it and set it as name (name = StringParser.unescapeString(name);). This works for me, but will check out your tipp. thanks

Comment: Good approach. But I think my solution is simplier. Moreover, the integration with IDE's (IntelliJ in my case) expects "" to link every step feature file <-> java class. Try it and good luck

Comment: Thanks! This works, but is more of a workaround for a missing feature in cucumber..

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass null values. When you pass an empty value, it will be seen as an empty string.
You could however change an empty value to a null value in your step definition file.